# How do I solve the problem of Build gradle?

Tags: android, flutter, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, gradle-plugin

I have just installed the filter but I am not able to run it
Every time I try to run it, I run into this problem
[image]

I tried to find the answer on the internet but could not find the answer
Some people said make changes to the gradle-wrapper.properties file
But he still did not answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That project is very old and cannot be opened using newer Android Studio versions because Gradle 4 is obsoleted.

Please use Studio 3.x.

Or try to upgrade to Gradle 7+ by editing "build.gradle", but it could require other changes in gradle files and/or included libraries.